# can angular ngModel is used to bind to the attribute of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want to know if there is an angular way of binding attribute of a HTML element to the ngModel.

for e.g. I have two HTML element and I want to change the widh of other element if the width of first element changes..I thought there will be some way to bind width property of first element to a model property and then using the same model to set the width of other element.

HOW to do this scenario angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be like...

```
<div ng-style="{'width':firstWidth}">
</div>
<div ng-style="{'width':secondWidth}">
</div>
```

And some controller code that is similar to...

```
$scope.firstWidth = 100 + "px";
$scope.secondWidth = $scope.firstWidth;
```

Then somewhere change first width and notice that second width would automatically change. In essence. I don't know if this is the best way as there are many ways to do this but here is the simplest.

Example for comments

```
<div ng-style="{'width':size}">
</div>
<div ng-style="{'width':size}">
</div>

 $scope.size = Whatever number your controller is giving you for this dynamic size
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this will need me to know when size is change on that event i have to assign width of first to second..what should be the event..isnt there some easy way without needing me to find that event and assign the property. width of my first element is going to change dynamically.

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit better I am having trouble understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I have two div tag..and i want width of those two tag should say similar..when application run various other elements are added in the first div and its width is increased..so i want the width of second element should also increase..based on first

Comment: okay but how are the tags dynamically changing size? where is this size coming from?

Comment: size is coming from one controller

Comment: So why can't you make an Observable variable ex: $scope.size = to what the size is and then using the technique above apply that size variable to each of the elements?

Comment: I got your point now..I am kind of new to web development..HTML size cannot change dynamically unless someone set it from javascript or we can say controller..I think i can use the method you said..

Comment: html itself doesn't offer this but using something like Angularjs helps extend the functionality of html. Which allows you to do dynamic data binding.

Comment: Note I put another example in my answer.

Comment: i just want to avoid writing bind event on resize event using jquery..i think i can do the way you said using angular..no need to use jquery here..thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

ok if i get you, the thing you wanna do is watch the width css property of a div that can dinamicly change it size have you try a watcher with function for that:

```
$scope.da_width = {};
$scope.elem = angular.element('div#first'); //jquery need it for this

$scope.$watch(function($scope) {return $scope.elem.css('width'); }, function(newValue) {
    $scope.da_width = { 'width': newValue };
});
```

this way youll always know what is the width of div#first and can be assigned to lets say div#two in your view or something:

```
<div id="two" ng-style="da_width">...</div>
```